Express: Using .route(), can I chain methods even if there are route params?
If I don't use .route(), I have to specify route every time:
const router = express.Router();

router
  .get('/book', handler)
  .post('/book', handler)
  .get('/book/:id', handler)
  .post('/book/:id', handler);

.route() allows grouping by a common route:
const apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.route('/book')
  .get()
  .post();

apiRouter.route('/book/:id')
  .get()
  .post();

But is there a syntax that allow me to chain those 2 together? Something like this:
const apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.route('/book')
  .get()
  .post()
  .route('/:id') // handle '/book/:id' from here
  .get()
  .post()

